# PhoneGap Userlogin Local storage

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am trying to create a user login application using Phonegap.
here is my code

```
function successCB(tx) {
    var setName = $("#name").val();
    var setID = $("#ID").val();

    //alert('select * from USER where name='+setID+' and password='+setName+'');
    tx.executeSql('select * from USER where name='+setID+' and password='+setName+'', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}
```

When I uncomment the alert, it shows the data enter from the text fields, however I cant figure out what to do next,

I want to check the inputs from the database and if user id and password are correct the flow should go to another page like a proper login page.

What is the appropriate way to do that in

```
function querySuccess(tx, results)
```

Comment: why do you pass MySQL statements to a javascript function?

Comment: @jycr753 this is part of phonegaps communication through cordova api localstorage.

Comment: @juan My bad, i totally forgot that you were using cordova api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to verify that some rows got selected.  If the typed in username and password was correct the sql sentense will return a row with that user.

Either you make a global variable called DB where you connection is stored.  Then you chould do something like this.

```
var db = "";

db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);


// collect your values as you already do.. i just showed em for demontration purpose..
var setName = $("#name").val();
var setID = $("#ID").val();


// execute this code from a function of your choice.
db.transaction(function(con) {
    con.executeSql('select * from USER where name='+setID+' and password='+setName+'', [], function (tx, results) {

       var len = results.rows.length;
       if (len==1) {alert("you logged in with some user");}

    }); 
});
```

Or with what you posted.

```
function querySuccess(tx, results) {
           var len = results.rows.length;
           if (len==1) {alert("you logged in with some user");}
}
```

So what you need to do after all this is to make sure that you can detect if you are logged in or not.  Its not of much use if you have to log in every time u change page or what your app contains.  You could use the localstorage to detect that.

You could also make a global variable to hold the value of loggedin or not.

:-)

I hope my code helped you.